# Rake: How do I forward params to child Rake calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

So, in my rake command, when I do --trace, it only does it on the command I manually execute, and none of the rake commands that the custom rake executes.

My Rake command:

```
namespace :db do
  task :regenesis do
    #because of how devestating this command could be, it's going 
    # to be forced to use the Test Environment
    puts "Re-Generating the Database"
    Rake::Task["db:drop RAILS_ENV=test --trace"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:create RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:create RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:bootstrap RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
  end
end
```

Twould be ideal to not have to hard code the --trace in there =D

So, I should be able to do rake db:regenesis --trace, and it should append trace onto all of those rake commands.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574921/passing-parameters-to-child-tasks-from-a-parent-task-in-rake). If you cannot modify your tasks to add the parameters ( for some reason ), then you can use environment variables, like:

```
namespace :db do
  task :regenesis do
    #because of how devestating this command could be, it's going 
    # to be forced to use the Test Environment
    puts "Re-Generating the Database"
    ENV["extra_option"] = "--trace"
    Rake::Task["db:drop RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:create RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:create RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
    Rake::Task["db:bootstrap RAILS_ENV=test"].invoke
  end
end
```

And in your tasks you'd have to look for `ENV["extra_option"]`